# Incremental Data Storage from MongoDB to Amazon S3 in Parquet Format

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a database in MongoDB. That is updating every minute from various user PCs. Now I want to store the data into Amazon S3 bucket (preferable in Parquet, otherwise CSV). But I do not want to store the full MongoDB data into S3 every-time. I only want to save the incremental data in S3.

I was thinking to use Kafka in between MongoDB and S3. But there are two issues in that:
Issue 1: I do not know how to store the incremental data from MongoDB to S3 in Parquet/CSV format without any paid solution
Issue 2: I do not know, whether this is a good/practical solution

Can anyone suggest any solution to achieve this kind of job please?

Comment: MinIO is a free, self hosted S3 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> store the incremental data from MongoDB (in Kafka)

Use Debezium or Mongo CDC connector

> do not want to store the full MongoDB

You can disable initial Debezium snapshot, but then any update/delete after starting the connector wouldn't be processed correctly.

> to S3 in Parquet/CSV format

Mongo documents typically aren't tables, so do not use CSV; Parquet handles nested data much better.

You can use Confluent S3 sink connector for this.

> without any paid solution

All the above are free / open source tools. S3 costs money unless you use an alternative solution such as MinIO. BUT, you're still paying for servers for running all these tools, and it'll probably be more costly to recover / maintain than using AWS S3 directly.

Comment: Actually i went thought all of this, and finally endedup spinning a JVM that listens to mongo and writes to s3. It was so simple.

Comment: @chendu What if something else wants that data? Would you rather write a lambda on S3? Or write a Kafka consumer?

Comment: yaa i get u. I dont remember the issues i had with debizium. But yes for your case i would also write to kafka along with s3. Actually in my curent usecase i cache documents at collection level. So i am thinking by just trying to consume from kafka --such usecases may get difficult to achieve

Comment: @OneCricketeer
Awesome proposal. I will try to follow this route. I will try to find out some documentation/video for such kind of process, as I am a new-bee in this domain

Answer (score 0):

Parquet will be very advantageous when you save huge data, say 10k rows. When you say incremental records, I am thinking you will be saving every minute and at max 1-4k records you may get. Saving as parquet will not be helpful here. Instead

1. use JSON --advantage being you don't have to worry about special chars/ encoding, column placements, nested columns etc. Gson parser will take care of all of them. Meaning read from Mongo cdc and write to JSON end of every 1minute (writing at end of minute will make sure that you have 1 fat file instead of 60 continuous files). Understand that S3 bills you by the number of file reads you do. Meaning, if you store as 60 files and read 60 files --it will be more costly than reading 1 single fat file
2. have a snapshot in Parquet. keep merging the Jsons to the parquet files using some Spark job.

You may alternatively consider delta bricks -- I myself have not used it. But the advantage is that you can keep writing to the data store in delta format and this delta bricks will take care of merging the data periodically (using vacuum command) -- and makes sure you get the latest Parquet always.

Comment: My DB is about 8GB. After different kind of joins on tables, dataset size becomes 20GB. I was thinking to use Parquet for that reason. Data transfer will be huge in first time. After that, only incremental data will be transferred. So, may be JSON will be the right one, as you advised.

I was thinking, S3 billing is dependent on total volume of data, not number of files. I missed to consider that. As you have pointed out, I need to consider other ways.

I was not aware about Data Bricks (I think you are mentioning Data Bricks instead of Delta)? I will explore that option too

Comment: both volume and files. 1TB = 25$ ; 1m reads = 5$

Comment: I wouldn't suggest JSON. Avro is row oriented and can be used to easily build parquet files

Comment: Hi chendu. Please use a spell-checker here if you can. Stack Overflow is not a chatroom or a forum - posts are kept in perpetuity, and we want them to be as readable as possible for future readers.